# Vim - buffer names in the cmd line area

Tags: vim

When I edit files with vim there is always this in the cmd line area,under the status line,all buffers' names(image : [image: http://ompldr.org/vOHZtdg])

Is there any way I can remove it?

Comment: Are you using some plugin for buffer management? By the way, you could also show us your vim settings.

Comment: What does `:set statusline` show as the current format string for your status bar?

Comment: This is the statusline in my .vimrc: set statusline=\ \%F%m%r%h%w\ ::\ %y\ \[#\%n\]\%=\ [%p%%:\ %v\::\%l/%L]\

Comment: @nozimica I'm using MiniBufExplorer if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your `vim` config file has some extra custom stuff somewhere because that's not part of the default package.

Try adding this to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
:set laststatus=0
```

You can test by just running that in an open editor.

**Edit:** Based on your reported status line, you should probably change:

```
set statusline=\ \%F%m%r%h%w\ ::\ %y\ [#\%n]\%=\ [%p%%:\ %v\::\%l/%L]\ –
```

…to:

```
set statusline=\ \%F%m%r%h%w\ ::\ %y\ [#\%n]
```

…but you may need to experiment to see which parts you want to keep and which parts are the line you don't want.

Comment: By setting laststatus=0 the statusbar dissapears,I want to hide only that text that appears under the statusline.

Comment: See my edit, it look like your status line preference just has more stuff than you want to see. You can par it down yourself.

Comment: Hmm,that doesn't work.Also the last part in the statusline is for percent , colon  , current line / all lines.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`buftabs.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1664) which modifies the `'statusline'` as you switch buffers, then restores `'stl'`.